# Adjusting vertical distance of equation number from equation

Tags: equations, formatting

While writing down some notes I encountered the following formatting problem that I would like to address

[image]

As you can see the equation numbering is really near the equation. I would like to make it go a little downwards, but i don't know why. If it helps, this is the TeX code and I'm using the [NotesTex package](https://ctan.org/pkg/notestex), but it shouldn't make any difference i think!

```
From the full differential decay rate
\begin{equation}
    d\Gamma = \half\frac{1}{2m_\mu}\frac{G_F^2}{2}(256)(\vb{p}_e\cdot\vb{p}_{\nu_\mu})
    (\vb{p}_{\bar \nu_e}\cdot\vb{p}_\mu)(2\pi)^4\delta^{(4)}(q-p_{\bar\nu_e}-p_{\nu_\mu})
    \frac{d^3p_e}{(2\pi)^3 2E_e}\frac{d^3 p_{\bar\nu_e}}{(2\pi)^32E_{\bar\nu_e}}
    \frac{d^3p_{\nu_\mu}}{(2\pi)^32E_{\nu_\mu}}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Since the formula is clearly overflowing the right margin I would not move the equation number, I'd break the formula for example after the delta.

Comment: @daleif Yeah, i was afraid of that. I'll break the equation then, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using the `multline` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, nccmath}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}

\newcommand\half{\frac12}
\newcommand{\vb}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{2}
\setcounter{equation}{21}

From the full differential decay rate
\begin{multline}
      d\Gamma = \smash[b]{\half\frac{1}{2m_\mu}\frac{G_F^2}{2}}(256)(\vb{p}_e\cdot\vb{p}_{\nu_\mu})
     (\vb{p}_{\bar \nu_e}\cdot\vb{p}_\mu)(2\pi)^4 \cdot{}\\
    {}\cdot \delta^{(4)}(q-p_{\bar\nu_e}-p_{\nu_\mu})
    \frac{d^3p_e}{(2\pi)^3 2E_e}\frac{d^3 p_{\bar\nu_e}}{(2\pi)^32E_{\bar\nu_e}}
    \frac{d^3p_{\nu_\mu}}{(2\pi)^32E_{\nu_\mu}}
\end{multline}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Cool, i didn't know the multline enviorment, that helps a lot, thanks!